# Remove n legend from ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to remove the 'n' legend from the following plot. I'm guessing it's related to the `stat` part of `geom_bar()` but am not entirely sure what it is showing and hence am not sure how to remove it. I do want the fill legend so `show.legends=FALSE` isn't the right option. Sorry if this is a duplicate but after
 a lot of looking I can't find the answer, changing the legend on a scale_x_x doesn't cover it.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,fill=Species))+
   geom_bar(stat="sum")
```

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Turning off some legends in a ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604435/turning-off-some-legends-in-a-ggplot)

Comment: I looked at this one @kath but it's not what is needed here

Comment: You can add  `+  guides(size = F)` to you plot, so yes it is not exactly there only `guides(color = F)`

Comment: Thanks kath that's perfect. The issue I was having was identifying it was the size element that was causing the issue, which James has helped with below

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can control legends with the `show.legend` parameter, with fine control by using a named vector:

> `show.legend`
>
> logical. Should this layer be included in the legends?
>   NA, the default, includes if any aesthetics are mapped. FALSE never
>   includes, and TRUE always includes. It can also be a named logical
>   vector to finely select the aesthetics to display.

The trick is to recognise that the n part of the legend comes from the size aesthetic.

```
ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Sepal.Width,fill=Species))+
+    geom_bar(stat="sum", show.legend=c(size=FALSE))
```

Comment: "The trick is to recognise that the n part of the legend comes from the size aesthetic", how did you notice it? (+1)

Comment: I used `str` on the plot object to see what was in it.

Comment: Alternatively, knowing the aes name you can use `+ guides(size = FALSE)`

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>%
    group_by(Species, Sepal.Length) %>%
    summarise(Sepal.Width = sum(Sepal.Width)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, fill = Species)) +
    geom_col()
```

[image]

Explanation: Summarise `Sepal.Width` per `Species` per `Sepal.Length` first, then plot. Generally (I think) it is advisable and tidier to keep data manipulations/summarisations and plotting separate.