# Using formulae on facet_wrap in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-wrap

I'm trying to replace the `facet_wrap` titles on a `ggplot` bar plot with expressions, but I'm having no luck. I've tried [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089052/r-ggplot2-facet-grid-how-include-math-expressions-in-few-not-all-labels) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11979017/changing-facet-label-to-math-formula-in-ggplot2) but neither seem to be working for me.

The whole dataset is quite large, so here's some dummy data to illustrate the problem.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

    data<-data.frame(species = rep(c("oak", "elm", "ash"), each = 5),
resp_1 = (runif(15, 1,100)),
resp_2 = (runif(15, 1,100)),
resp_3 = (runif(15, 1,100)),
resp_4 = (runif(15, 1,100)),
resp_5 = (runif(15, 1,100)))

### transform to longform with tidyr

data_2 <- gather(data, response, result, resp_1:resp_5, factor_key=TRUE)

### plot with ggplot2

ggplot(data_2, aes(x = species, y = result, fill = species))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'sum')+
  facet_wrap(~ response)

### here are the labels I'd like to see on the facets

oxygen <-expression ("Oxygen production (kg/yr)")
runoff <-expression("Avoided runoff " ~ (m ^{3} /yr))
co <- expression("CO removal (g/yr)")
o3 <- expression("O"[3]~" removal (g/yr)")
no2 <- expression("NO"[2]~" removal (g/yr)")

labels <- c(oxygen, runoff, co, o3, no2)

### this doesn't work 

ggplot(data_2, aes(x = species, y = result, fill = species))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'sum')+
  facet_wrap(~ response, labeller = labeller(response = labels))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
### close, but doesn't work

levels(data_2$response)<-labels


ggplot(data_2, aes(x = species, y = result, fill = species))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'sum')+
  facet_wrap(~ response, labeller = labeller(response = labels))
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
### produces an error

ggplot(data_2, aes(x = species, y = result, fill = species))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'sum')+
  facet_wrap(~ response, labeller = label_parsed)
```

I'd also like to get rid of the second legend in grey titled "n".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now your expression names don't match up to the values used as the facets. So I'd recommend storing your labels in an expression

```
labels <- expression(
  resp_1 = "Oxygen production (kg/yr)",
  resp_2 = "Avoided runoff " ~ (m ^{3} /yr),
  resp_3 = "CO removal (g/yr)",
  resp_4 = "O"[3]~" removal (g/yr)",
  resp_5 = "NO"[2]~" removal (g/yr)"
)
```

And then you can write your own labeler function to extract the correct value

```
ggplot(data_2, aes(x = species, y = result, fill = species))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'sum', show.legend = c(size=FALSE))+
  facet_wrap(~ response, labeller = function(x) {
    list(as.list(labels)[x$response])
  })
```

[image: facet grid with expressions]

We've also used `show.legend = c(size=FALSE)` to [turn off the `n` legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965341/remove-n-legend-from-ggplot)

Comment: that this works looks like pure magic to me. I would have never thought you can create lists like that. Very cool.

Answer (score 4):

Use `as_labeller` and `label_parsed`. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55438500/786542)

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(species = rep(c("oak", "elm", "ash"), each = 5),
                   resp_1 = (runif(15, 1, 100)),
                   resp_2 = (runif(15, 1, 100)),
                   resp_3 = (runif(15, 1, 100)),
                   resp_4 = (runif(15, 1, 100)),
                   resp_5 = (runif(15, 1, 100)))
data_2 <- gather(data, response, result, resp_1:resp_5, factor_key = TRUE)

# setup the labels
reponse_names <- c(
  `resp_1` = "Oxygen~production~(kg*yr^{-1})",
  `resp_2` = "Avoided~runoff~(m^{3}*yr^{-1})",
  `resp_3` = "CO~removal~(g*yr^{-1})",
  `resp_4` = "O[3]~removal~(g*yr^{-1})",
  `resp_5` = "NO[2]~removal~(g*yr^{-1})"
)

# plot
ggplot(data_2, aes(x = species, y = result, fill = species))+
  geom_bar(stat = 'sum')+
  facet_wrap(
    ~ response,
    labeller = labeller(response  = as_labeller(reponse_names,  label_parsed))
  ) +
  guides(size = "none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>